# .NoSuchFileException saving error in Java

Tags: java, save

I'm trying to save my first project and I keep getting this error, I'm following along with a book and I don't really know what went wrong?

jshell> /save ~/Desktop/filename.txt
|  File '~/Desktop/filename.txt' for '/save' threw exception: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\klbad\Desktop\filename.txt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076063/how-to-solve-the-java-nio-file-nosuchfileexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `/save ~/Desktop/filename.txt`

`~` has no meaning in Windows. It's a Unix shell thing.
I'm not sure whether you'd get away with forward slashes either (I can't test it as not in Windows)

Comment: thank you!! the / slashes do work btw i was able to /reset it before it just doesnt read the ~ ,do you know what i can use in the ~'s place?

Comment: Not at the moment, I'm afraid. My experiments failed :(