# Google Cloud Storage Not Always Downloading File

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot application which uses the GCP Pub/Sub binder with Spring Cloud Streams to listen for an event GCP posts to a topic when a file is loaded into a specific bucket. The spring boot application would then need to take the file referenced in the pub/sub message, download it to the temp directory, process it, then delete it from local storage. It successfully processes 371 files all dumped into the directory, but there were 137 files that all threw the same error. The following is the method throwing the exception, and the exception itself

```
    private Optional<List<SingleImport>> load(StorageObjectMessage storageObjectMessage, Storage storage) throws JAXBException {
 
        ImportLoader loader = new ImportLoader();
        FileConverter converter = new FileConverter();
        Blob blob = storage.get(blobId);
        Optional<List<SingleImport>> result = Optional.empty();
 
        log.info(String.format("%s blob with id of %s", blob == null ? "Could not find" : "Found", blobId.getName()));
 
        if(blob != null) {
 
            String systemTemporaryDirectory = String.format("%s%s.tmp", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), storageObjectMessage.getMd5Hash());
            log.info(String.format("Downloading file for processing to temp directory at %s", systemTemporaryDirectory));
            blob.downloadTo(Paths.get(systemTemporaryDirectory));
            File tempFile = new File(systemTemporaryDirectory);
            Import importModel = loader.load(tempFile);
            List<SingleImport> singleImport = converter.convert(importModel);
            result = Optional.of(singleImport);
 
        }
 
        return result;
 
    }
```

```
2022-03-17 10:43:43.380  INFO 39483 --- [sub-subscriber1] c.h.mro2go.sap.service.FileService       : Found blob with id of update/inbound/cat_upd_20220104124110-00028.xml
2022-03-17 10:43:43.380  INFO 39483 --- [sub-subscriber1] c.h.mro2go.sap.service.FileService       : Downloading file for processing to temp directory at /var/folders/dk/4k5hcmcj1zv43kx0pgpys8j80000gq/T/jrrpW/f1JEx0uFQDq2xsVQ==.tmp
com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: /var/folders/dk/4k5hcmcj1zv43kx0pgpys8j80000gq/T/jrrpW/f1JEx0uFQDq2xsVQ==.tmp
       at com.google.cloud.storage.Blob.downloadTo(Blob.java:237)
       at com.google.cloud.storage.Blob.downloadTo(Blob.java:274)
       at com.hdsupply.mro2go.sap.service.FileService.load(FileService.java:90)
       at com.hdsupply.mro2go.sap.service.FileService.retrieveNewFile(FileService.java:42)
       at com.hdsupply.mro2go.sap.message.SapEventConsumer.processFile(SapEventConsumer.java:56)
       at com.hdsupply.mro2go.sap.message.SapEventConsumer.accept(SapEventConsumer.java:35)
       at com.hdsupply.mro2go.sap.message.SapEventConsumer.accept(SapEventConsumer.java:1)
       at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.invokeConsumer(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:975)
       at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:704)
       at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:550)
       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.apply(PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.java:84)
       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionWrapper.apply(FunctionConfiguration.java:749)
       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.handleMessageInternal(FunctionConfiguration.java:581)
       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
       at com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.integration.inbound.PubSubInboundChannelAdapter.consumeMessage(PubSubInboundChannelAdapter.java:144)
       at com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate.lambda$subscribeAndConvert$1(PubSubSubscriberTemplate.java:173)
       at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageDispatcher$4.run(MessageDispatcher.java:396)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/folders/dk/4k5hcmcj1zv43kx0pgpys8j80000gq/T/jrrpW/f1JEx0uFQDq2xsVQ==.tmp
       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:218)
       at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:484)
       at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:228)
       at com.google.cloud.storage.Blob.downloadTo(Blob.java:234)
       ... 33 more
```

What might be causing this to happen at all, let alone only some of the time?

Comment: What's the content type of those files?

Comment: application/xml

Comment: The files you are having issues with are of a particular size, length, format, or have a character? Can you also please provide the complete error message?

Comment: Attached is the entire stack trace. Everything else is irrelevant logs that have nothing to do with that specific process. The files are all around 12MB large, however other files larger than 12MB were able to be successfully processed. There are no character or encoding format differences.

Comment: I have been investigating the error and its caused by the default directory at application startup.  Check this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076063/how-to-solve-the-java-nio-file-nosuchfileexception) and see if the accepted answer can help you.